# Source control unable to access database

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git

```
The associated source control plug-in is not installed or could not be initialized.
Common causes for this error include server unavailability and/or incorrect workspace mappings.

O Temporarily work uncontrolled
o Permanentnly remove source control association bindings
```

Dear friends,

I have installed git and also the git extension,
I have used the clone repository properly,
The git system is working fine on my system,  yet I m getting this error

What is the problem?The mappings?
How to solve it... :(

Comment: Looks like http://gittf.codeplex.com/discussions/393628: what version of git-tf are you using?

Comment: I have installed Tortoise git and Git-Extension.I donno about git-tf.I have made a repo using git and using that only.

Comment: I installed the git plugin available for Visual studio and I think it solved the issue.

Comment: Ok, I have formalized that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP reports that installing the git plugin for Visual Studio (should be "[Visual Studio Tools for Git](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c) "), the error message is gone.

Answer (score 0):

**The common resolution is often to flush the local cache by completing the following steps:**

Delete the contents from the following folders

C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation

C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio

C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon

Go to the Visual Studio IDE folder in command prompt and Run the following command "devenv /resetuserdata" from the Visual Studio IDE folder.

Typical location for 64 bit:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

Typical location for 32 bit:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

Before following the above step please close all instance of your visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a Global section in the file, which is where all of the settings for this are located. look for GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) and remove that entire section down to EndGlobalSection.

Once you do that, reload the solution and tell it to go back online and your bindings should be working again.